# How to call a function on ready on jquery mobile- phonegap?

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have an index page (index.html) that user can go from it to login page (login.html)

So to move to login.html I do this:

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "login.html",
{transition: "none", changeHash: false, reload: true});
```

But on login.html I want to call some functions when page is loaded. So I tried the following but they did not work (not triggered)

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#loginPage", function( event ) {  
alert( "This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!" ); });
```

or this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to fix it.
I loaded all the .js files on index.html

And I put the following line on index.js

```
$('#loginPage').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){    
       init(); // this is defined on login.js

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The most important point in developing cordova is to listen to the cordova deviceready event:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", startApp, false);

function startApp(){
   // begin your app logic here
}
```

Another tip: Don't create multi-site layouts with several html files. It will slow down your app and it is more difficult to develop.

Comment: Also make sure you load you assets (Javascript, CSS, etc.) locally, not from the Internet.

Comment: You will be surprised how times I hear. "Why should I do that?" FWIW, I prefer several html files for \*some\* apps, as it is easier. But in many cases, I think you are right.

Comment: But I  was able to work it with different html files. However all java script files should be loaded on the header index file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '#loginPage' ).on( 'pagebeforeshow',function(event){
 alert( "This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!" ); });
}
```